# Statistics - (bivariate data) Planning an Inquiry

Tags: self-study, sample, population

I have to conduct a statistical inquiry that is representative of a population. You have to choose from a list of situations, and my choice was to measure the weight and length of carrots.

The question of my investigation is "Is there a relationship between a measure of length and weight of a carrot?"

My sample has to consist of at least 30 items.

How can my sample be representative? How do I even go about taking a sample? I can't exactly go to a carrot field and pick carrots using a random sampling method. If I purchased carrots from a supermarket, wouldn't it be biased? I have to explain all this as apart of the planning process...

Answer (score 3):

First off, you have to pick A population.  Not THE population.  So you could define your population any way you want to that's reasonable. You have two examples already: carrot fields and supermarkets. Even that needs further specification (e.g. you are doing this now, and perhaps the carrots one would buy in March would be a different variety / size  -- also supermarkets in Baltimore may have different suppliers than ones in Vancouver ).

The key to sampling is to pick

a population you care about (e.g. voters in a specific election),

a sampling frame (e.g. a list of registered voters) that seems well matched to the population you care about.

and then look at ways to pick the sample.

Sometimes we have to work backwards.  We have some possible sampling frames, and then we figure out that a particular sampling frame enables us to generalize to a specific population that might be slightly different than the one we originally started with.

If you can't generalize to all carrots all over the world for all possible times, so be it. It is a common analytical mistake to mismatch sample, sampling frame, and population, but that doesn't mean you have to make that mistake.